# Splitting extremely large file into smaller files but organize into subdirectories

Tags: regex, bash, file, shell, awk

I have a very large file about 10Gigs But would like to split the given file into smaller files based on a regex pattern. Currently I have a working solution

```
      awk '/<doc/{x="F"++i".xml";}{print > ("sub/"x);close("sub/"x);}' wiki_parsed.xml
```

This generates the smaller files based on the given regex doc and saves them in the folder "sub" However all the files are saved into the directory sub. Which ends up at about a few hundred thousand files. I would like the script to store the files into sub-directories recursively storing about a few hundred files in each. Any suggestions ?

Comment: How about putting this much info into a database? If you're really certain that "few hundred thousand files" is the best route, how about a little analysis of the data, using data elements to make the subdirectory names self-documenting. A simple, but often used case is to make sub dirs by date of data, so you have a dir like 2014/05/05.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a threshold of how many files you'd like to create in a particular directory and create a new sub-directory when that threshold is reached.

```
awk '
BEGIN { system("mkdir -p sub"++j) }
/<doc/ {
    x = "F"++i".txt"
}
{ 
    print > ("sub"j"/"x);
    if(i%5==0) { 
        close("sub"j"/"x); 
        system("mkdir -p sub"++j) 
    }
}
END { 
    system ("rmdir sub"j)
}' file
```

Take the following example (this creates a new sub-directory after 5 files have been written to it):

```
$ seq 20 > file

$ ls
file

$ awk '
BEGIN { system("mkdir -p sub"++j) }
/./ {
    x = "F"++i".txt"
}
{ 
    print > ("sub"j"/"x);
    if(i%5==0) { 
        close("sub"j"/"x); 
        system("mkdir -p sub"++j) 
    }
}
END { 
    system ("rmdir sub"j)
}' file

$ ls
file  sub1  sub2  sub3  sub4

$ ls sub*
sub1:
F1.txt  F2.txt  F3.txt  F4.txt  F5.txt

sub2:
F10.txt  F6.txt  F7.txt  F8.txt  F9.txt

sub3:
F11.txt  F12.txt  F13.txt  F14.txt  F15.txt

sub4:
F16.txt  F17.txt  F18.txt  F19.txt  F20.txt
```

You can tweak the `awk` command to suit your needs and requirement.

Comment: +1; re `close(...)`: it's missing the `j`. Performance considerations: may make sense to move the `close(...)` call into the `if(i%5...` branch. The biggest performance gain would come from only calling `system(...)`  with `mkdir -p` when needed.

Comment: @mklement0 Good points. Have updated the solution. Though I had to create an `END` block to delete the last created empty directory.

Comment: Thanks for updating; You could get away with a single `system()` call if you placed the `if` statement before the `print` and added additional checks, e.g.: `if (j==0 || i%5==0) { if (j>0) close("sub"j"/"x); system("mkdir -p sub"++j) }`; also, given that the printing block is executed _un_conditionally, `x` should be initialized.

Comment: @mklement0 Valid points again. I'll leave them on OP to play with. `:)`

Comment: Thanks guys for really constructive comments. and a great answer. But i now have a too many files are open error when i run this code.https://gist.github.com/xecutioner/6ceff4ee31f1e41ae825 . If we could work to close the files properly then that would be awesome.

Comment: @xecutioner We disregarded the fact that now `close` is inside a loop which means it will only close every 5th file and leave every other file open. Try running this code http://ideone.com/QNbewH

Comment: Thanks @jaypal for prompt answer. But just a curiosity if we close every file would there would be too much disk I/O. If so would it cause some major performance lag in handling huge files.

Comment: I can't say for sure but keep too many file open has far greater performance hit then closing them.

Answer (score 0):

This got it just the perfect way i wanted it to function.

This is what i got it to be working perfectly

```
awk 'BEGIN { system("mkdir -p splitted/sub"++j) }
 /<doc/{x="F"++i".xml";}{

  if (i%1995==0 ){
   ++i;
   system("mkdir -p splitted/sub"++j"/");
  }
  else{
   print >> ("splitted/sub"j"/"x);
   close("splitted/sub"j"/"x);
  }

 }' wiki_parsed.xml
```

Thanks a lot guys